# Why does accessing a private variable in another closure's scope via prototypical inheritance allowed?

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

So I was able to access a private variable (`numb`) accidentally via prototypical inheritance.  I have a couple of questions:

1. Shouldn't these private variables in a self-invoking anonymous function (SIAF) closure have expired already after the SIAF finished executing? I was expecting it to error out because of `'use strict'`.
2. If it's meant for the variable to never expire, Should this be avoided as part of best practice?

Here's the code:

```
'use strict';

var GLOBAL = {};


// SELF-INVOKING ANONYMOUS FUNCTION
(function(){

    var numb = 110;
    var Person = function(first_name, last_name) {
        this.name = first_name + ' ' + last_name;
    };

    Person.prototype.getNumb = function() { return numb; };

    GLOBAL.Person = Person;
})();


// ANOTHER SELF-INVOKING ANONYMOUS FUNCTION
(function(){
    function Animal(type_of_animal) {
      this.type = type_of_animal; 
    }

    Animal.prototype = Object.create(GLOBAL.Person.prototype);
    GLOBAL.Animal = Animal;
})();



var dog = new GLOBAL.Animal('dog'); 
console.log( dog.getNumb() ); // This logs 110 to the console.
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6w2L1y5w/1/

Comment: That's how closures work, since you reference `numb`. Note that you reuse `numb` for every instance though.

Comment: The code works totally as expected. `getNumb` is a closure, accessing variables from the SIAF scope, whereever it is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable scope in Javascript is lexical. That means, the scope is exactly as written in the source. The function `getNumb` is defined in the same lexical scope as the variable `numb` and its body is referring to that variable (`return numb`). It doesn't matter how or from where you call that function. This is how closures work.

In fact, this is how "privileged accessors" are implemented in Javascript: you have one "private" variable and one "public" function which has access to that variable through the scope it's defined in.

*(I'm using a lot of "quotes" around "private" and "public" here since those are traditional OOP visibility concepts which only vaguely transfer to Javascript. Javascript has simple lexical variable scope, period. "Privacy" and such is just applying this scoping mechanism in certain patterns to emulate class based OOP semantics.)*